# Is it possible to change the default order of SPList.Items?

Tags: splist, sorting, splistitemcollection

In my code, I am simply using SPList.Items which is returning all items (SPListItemCollection) with default sorting order (ascending order by Created date).

I know that I can use CAML Query or some other technique in my code to get the list items in required sort order but I don't want to make changes to my code. Is it possible to change the default order without making any changes to the existing code?

I am searching for an option like, just change a property of the List using SharePoint Manager and get the required sorting order when using SharePoint API (SPList.Items). Is there any such property available?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible, you will need to change the code.

Comment: do you want to get data in descending order without making change in code?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. I would suggest to use the CAML query which you do not want to use.